# Embedding value into string in .resx file

Tags: c#

Assuming I have a string which looks like:

```
@"Error in {id}."
```

Where the `id` value is not set in the Resource file, but only when the resource is needed.

How would write that in the `Value` area of a Resources file? Simply copying in the string does not work. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use String.Replace over "{id}" or write your resource like "Error in {0}" and use String.Format :?. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963270/should-we-store-format-strings-in-resources

Comment: Generally accepted is to use parameters as `{0}`, `{1}` etc so they can easily be inserted automatically using `String.Format`.